# Phonegap iOS app stuck at launchscreen

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I am working on a iOS application in Phonegap.The first time I run it everything works fine and the splash screen goes away. You login, an api token gets stored in the local storage, and you do what you want to do. The next attempts you make you get stuck in the splash screen. When I check if there are any errors in the js console, there are none. When I check the simulator log I have this failure

> Jun 28 10:46:32 Sebastiaans-MBP FitParck[11089]: assertion failed: 17F77 15F79: libxpc.dylib + 71445 [C070AA3B-6F2B-3D85-887C-5A00FAE39163]: 0x7d

Because this only happens after I login and use the local storage. I am pretty certain it must be something with the local storage and iOS specific, because my android app works just fine.
Hopefully you guys have any suggestions. If you have questions or want me to provide something just leave a comment.

Comment: iam having the same problem..any update regarding this question?

Comment: @Sanjay I know I fixed this. Only I tried so much that I do not remember anymore what exactly fixed it.